# How can I annotate?

Tags: django, django-models

How can I annotate all copies_sold of books for each `Author`

```
from django.db import models
from django.db.models import Count


class AuthorQuerySet(models.QuerySet):
    def annotate_with_copies_sold(self):
        return Author.objects.annotate(num_copies=Count('books__copies_sold'))


class AuthorManager(models.Manager):
    def get_queryset(self):
        return AuthorQuerySet(self.model, using=self._db)

    def annotate_with_copies_sold(self):
        return self.get_queryset().annotate_with_copies_sold()


class Author(models.Model):
    objects = AuthorManager()
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)


class Book(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    copies_sold = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    author = models.ForeignKey(Author, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='books')
```

Asserts failed

```
Output (stderr):
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/unittest/case.py", line 59, in testPartExecutor
    yield
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/unittest/case.py", line 605, in run
    testMethod()
  File "/task/assignment/tests.py", line 92, in test_annotating_works_with_filtering
    "Annotating with copies sold should work well with filtering")
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/unittest/case.py", line 829, in assertEqual
    assertion_func(first, second, msg=msg)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/unittest/case.py", line 822, in _baseAssertEqual
    raise self.failureException(msg)
AssertionError: 3 != 2 : Annotating with copies sold should work well with filtering


Output (stderr):
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/unittest/case.py", line 59, in testPartExecutor
    yield
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/unittest/case.py", line 605, in run
    testMethod()
  File "/task/assignment/tests.py", line 29, in test_should_annotate
    self.assertIsNotNone(Author.objects.annotate_with_copies_sold().first().copies_sold,
AttributeError: 'Author' object has no attribute 'copies_sold'
RUNTIME ERROR
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a `Count`, but a `Sum`:

```
from django.db.models import Sum

class AuthorQuerySet(models.QuerySet):

    def annotate_with_copies_sold(self):
        return Author.objects.annotate(num_copies=Sum('books__copies_sold'))
```

Each `Book` contains an integer that contains the number of copies sold, so in order to retrieve the total number, you sum up these numbers for all the books written by that author.

For `Author`s with no related `Book`s (that satisfy the filter), we can use an [**`Coalesce`** expression [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/database-functions/#coalesce):

```
from django.db.models import Sum, V
from django.db.models.functions import Coalesce

class AuthorQuerySet(models.QuerySet):

    def annotate_with_copies_sold(self):
        return Author.objects.annotate(num_copies=Coalesce(Sum('books__copies_sold'), V(0)))
```

Comment: Thnx, but I get two errors: 1. `AssertionError: 3 != 2 : Annotating with copies sold should work well with filtering`. 2. `AttributeError: 'Author' object has no attribute 'copies_sold'`

Comment: @ДмитрийДмитрук: can you include the tests you make that fail. At first sight, it looks like you do not use the manager and/or queryset API the correct way.

Comment: @ДмитрийДмитрук: shouldn't the second test be `self.assertIsNotNone(Author.objects.annotate_with_copies_sold().first().num_copies, ...` (so with `num_copies` instead of `copies_sold`?

Comment: I can not debug the first one, since it is not clear what filtering you do here.

Comment: Thanks. Akso two errors - `AssertionError: unexpectedly None : Annotated authors should have copies_sold attribute`, `None != 0 : The copies_sold attribute should be 0 when the author has no books`

Comment: @ДмитрийДмитрук: you can use `Coalesce` to use zero for the sum of an empty related queryset.

Comment: 'Coalesce' object has no attribute 'default_alias'

Comment: It looks like you did not wrote `num_copies=...`, but just `.annotate(Coalesce(..))` (so without a *named* parameter).

Answer (score 3):

**This Shall help You guys :**

```
from django.db import models
from django.db.models import Sum
from django.db.models.functions import Coalesce

class AuthorManager(models.Manager):
    def get_queryset(self):
        return AuthorQuerySet(self.model, using=self._db)
    
    def annotate_with_copies_sold(self):
        return self.get_queryset().annotate_with_copies_sold()

class AuthorQuerySet(models.QuerySet):
    def annotate_with_copies_sold(self):
        # Write your solution here
        return self.annotate(copies_sold=Coalesce(Sum('books__copies_sold'), 0))


class Author(models.Model):
    # Make sure this manager is available.
    objects = AuthorManager()
    # objects = models.Manager.from_queryset(AuthorQuerySet)()
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)


class Book(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    copies_sold = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    author = models.ForeignKey(Author, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='books')
```